# Throw an exception inside the method body and catch it after

Tags: java, exception

The main class:

```
class IO 
{
    static void m() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
        } finally{
            System.out.println("finally");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        try {
            m();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
             System.out.println("catch");
        }
        System.out.println("finish");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
finally
catch
finish
```

That behavior is unclear for me. Clause 11.3 of JLS 8 says:

> If no catch clause that can handle an exception can be found, then the
>   **current thread (the thread that encountered the exception) is**
>   **terminated**. Before termination, all finally clauses are executed and
>   the uncaught exception is handled according to the following rules:
>
> If the current thread has an uncaught exception handler set, then that
>   handler is executed.
>
> Otherwise, the method uncaughtException is invoked for the ThreadGroup that is the parent > of the current thread.  If the ThreadGroup and its parent ThreadGroups do not override
>   uncaughtException, then the default handler's uncaughtException method is invoked.

I expected that the output will be `finally` only because current thread is terminated. I haven't produced any other threads, since the output must be `finally`, but it is not true. Help me to understand, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **If no catch clause that can handle an exception can be found**, [...]

But you do have a `catch` clause that can handle the exception. Your `m` method will complete abruptly as a result of the exception being thrown. [The exception will be caught and handle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)d inside your `main` method which will then complete normally along with the main thread.

Comment: But that `catch` belongs to the different try statements, which appears inside the `main()` method, rather than in inside the `m()`.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Any exception that is thrown within a `try` statement is potentially caught by a corresponding `catch` block, regardless of how far down the call stack the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to look at it like this, by replacing the function with the code from it.

```
class IO 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        try { //4 Now goes to the outer try
            try //2 Checks this try for the catch, but doesn't find it
            {
                throw new Exception(); //1 Hits the exception
            } finally{ //3 Executes this because there is no catch for this try
                System.out.println("finally");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { //5 Finds the catch
             System.out.println("catch");
        }
        //6 Continues as if nothing happened
        System.out.println("finish");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the flow:

```
    class IO 
    {
        static void m() throws Exception
        {
            try
            {   //2
                throw new Exception();
            } finally{
                    //3
                System.out.println("finally");
            }
        }
        public static void main(String [] args) 
        {
            try {
                m();//1 method called
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                  //4 the control returns
                 System.out.println("catch");
            }
                //5
            System.out.println("finish");
        }
    }
```

The thread is only terminated if the exception is not handled.